# Limit of ratio of binomial coefficients

Tags: probability, combinatorics, limits

How can I find the limit of

$$
\binom{n-a+r-2}{r-2}\bigg/\binom{n + r - 1}{ r - 1}
$$

as $n\to\infty, r\to\infty, \text{ and } n/r\to\rho > 0$?

---

Here's what I've tried. By definition of binomial coefficient, we get

$$\frac{(n - a + r - 2)!}{(r - 2)!(n - a)!} \cdot \frac{(r - 1)!n!}{(n + r - 1)!} $$

Then you can do $(r - 1)!/(r - 2)! = (r - 1)$, but I don't know what to do next. Someone said they think you might get $\rho^{a} e^{-\rho}/a!$ (this might not be right) as the limit but I have no clue how to even simplify this fraction.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: I have tried to use Stirling's already with no luck

Comment: Suggestion:  I "expanded" the numerator and denominator and cancelled like factors.  I got $a+1$ factors in the numerator and denominator.  Pairing those up, each fraction converged to either $\rho/(\rho+1)$ or $1/(\rho+1)$.

Comment: "Someone" (i.e. me) was not right.  Ali Ashja's result suggests geometric distribution on the non-negative integers with parameter $\frac{1}{\rho+1}$

Answer (score 2):

As @metamorphy said, you can use Stirling Approximation and solve it.

But if want to attack it directly:
$$\frac{(n-a+r-2)!}{(n+r-1)!}.\frac{(r-1)!}{(r-2)!}.\frac{(n)!}{(n-a)!} =$$
$$= \frac{1}{(n+r-1)...(n-a+r-1)}.\frac{(r-1)}{1}.\frac{(n)...(n-a+1)}{1} \simeq$$
$$\simeq \frac{1}{(n+r)^{a+1}}.\frac{(r)^1}{1}.\frac{(n)^a}{1} \simeq \frac{1}{(r \rho +r)^{a+1}}.\frac{(r)^1}{1}.\frac{(r \rho)^a}{1} = \frac{\rho^a}{(\rho +1)^{a+1}}$$